# Easiest algorithm to partition multiple (possibly) overlapping ranges

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, partitioning, data-partitioning

Suppose I have a vector of ranges and I want to partition them into multiple partitions.  Note that this is not the same as what std::partition does, which is to find a single partition point.  I'm wondering if there's an STL or boost (or other) for this?

To illustrate what I'm asking, let's start with the vector of ranges:

```
using Index = int;

struct Range
{
   // Indexes are inclusive, meaning this specifies [lo, hi] not [lo, hi)
   Index lo;
   Index hi; // hi is always guaranteed to be greater than lo
};
std:vector<Range> ranges = { {0, 3}, 
                             {1, 5}, 
                             {2, 4} };
```

What I would like to do is to have a function that partitions the ranges so that I end up with something like this:

```
std::map<Index, int> my_map = partition(ranges); // <<<--- This is the function I'm seeking
                 ^
                 |
                 +-- This 'int' is the partition number
```

The map it generates would look like this (given the data above):

```
my_map = { {0, 0},    // Lower bound of 0 for partition 0, which is [0, 1)
           {1, 1},    // Lower bound of 1 for partition 1, which is [1, 2)
           {2, 2},    // Lower bound of 2 for partition 2, which is [2, 4)
           {4, 3},    // Lower bound of 4 for partition 3, which is [4, 5)
           {5, 4}, }; // Lower bound of 5 for partition 4, which is [5, ...]
```

Now when I want to know what partition something is in:

```
Partition which(Index i)
{
    auto it = my_map.upper_bound(i);
    if (it != my_map.end())
        return (--it)->second;
    return my_map.size() - 1;
}
```

Comment: [Boost.ICL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) might be a candidate. but it also might be overkill. The general keyword you are looking for could be [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: Why not partition based on the first predicate and then partition the rest based on the second and so on? Would that not work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that boost::icl does the trick... Credit to @sascha